# CakePHP Error: Database table acos for model Aco was not found

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a Mac running Mac OS X Leopard at work as well as at home and a PC at work as well.

I have the project I'm currently working on set up on all 3, it works fine at my work computers but on my home Mac I get the error in the title. The project is on SVN so I just checked it out ran the SQL script for my DB schema and set up the same user I have in my work DB and it will not work still.

I also cleared out the cache folders as suggested in other posts with a similar problem and it still won't work.

Obviously I have checked the database table and it is present in my DB. Anyone have any other clues as to what might be happening?

Comment: What SQL script did you run? One with a full data dump from your work dev? I agree with @Jason, post the full error, it's hard to know otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure it's connecting to the correct db?  Try disabling auth and seeing if the app works otherwise.

Comment: Cakes error message is obviously. It can't find the needed table "acos". So there must be a problem either with:
1. Your connection
2. Your database (your schema) or
3. Your connection config.
Check those first to make sure the table is present and that you connect to the right database.

Comment: That is the full error, I updated my post with screen shots

Comment: @Tyler how would I disable the Auth to check?

Comment: have you tried with the build_acl function? maybe your are forgetting about it... I would try it just in case

Comment: Wherever you have Auth included in your components list, remove it.  This would be in the `$components` var at the top of your controller or possibly app controller.

Comment: Tyler, I removed it and nothing happened I still get the error

Comment: Can you also fix these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the error was in my database user configuration. It seems I forgot to set CRUD permissions to the user I use to access the database and that's what gave me the error

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't in debug mode, I would suggest doing that to help troubleshoot.  If it works in debug mode, then you've got some sort of caching issue.  If it doesn't work in debug mode, my next question is - are your work computers windows?  If so, I would look at case-sensitivity issues because Windows and Macs handle case differently.

Comment: One of my work computer is a Mac the other Windows, and it works on both of them

Comment: Also I have debug mode set to 2, so I don't believe is a cache issue

Comment: Do other portions of your app work on this Mac and only this one fails?

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same error. Table creation worked fine from the shell, so it seemed dubious that it wouldn't be able to read it afterwards.

In my case, the fix was to empty cache / tmp folder, as suggested on [this french forum](http://forum.cakephp-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=4221).