# "Database table acos for model Aco was not found" error in remote server but correct in my local

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

After running my Cake application locally i tried to upload it to my
remote server, configured everything properly, checked all the tables,
database access. But I couldn't solve the following error. I can't
find enough resources too.

Missing Database Table
Error: Database table acos for model Aco was not found.

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/
errors/missing_table.ctp

I used the ACL component.

Comment: If the table truly exists, have you made sure the cache has been cleared and is writable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP Error: Database table acos for model Aco was not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052959/cakephp-error-database-table-acos-for-model-aco-was-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table exists but I found this link: 
[CakePHP Error: Database table acos for model Aco was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052959/cakephp-error-database-table-acos-for-model-aco-was-not-found) and this answer from [8vius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478108/8vius). By thanks from all.

The answer is:
In the end the error was in my database user configuration. It seems I forgot to set CRUD permissions to the user I use to access the database and that's what gave me the error

Comment: Moral of the story: search before asking